# WCF Service netTCPbinding

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-binding

I want to use netTCPbinding, so I've changed my web config as below. I'm experiencing this error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

How can this be solved?

```
<services>
  <service name="DXDirectory.DXDirectoryService" behaviorConfiguration="DXDirectory.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WindowsSecured" contract="DXDirectory.IDXDirectoryService">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:2582/DXDirectoryService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DXDirectory.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups" />
      <!--<serviceCredentials>-->
        <!--<userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                membershipProviderName="CustomUserNameValidator"/>-->
      <!--</serviceCredentials>-->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Want to know much more about NetTcpBinding in WCF... 
Visit this link it has lots of information.. 
http://www.planetofcoders.com/nettcpbinding-in-wcf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HMm... you've added the base address to your services/host section ok.

Quick question: are you self-hosting, or hosting in IIS ?? Which version of IIS ??

IIS5/6 only support HTTP connections - you cannot host a NetTCP in IIS 5/6.

In IIS7, you have to manually go through a series of steps to enable non-HTTP bindings, but it's possible. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx) on how to achieve this.

Self-hosting is the best option - you get all bindings and are in total control of your service being hosted.

Marc

Comment: I am using self hosting and IIS 7

Comment: Sorry Marc, I am using IIS 5.1

Comment: As I mentioned - IIS5 will *not* work with the NetTCP binding - you'll need to use self-hosting in this case. Do you have the same error in self-hosting, too?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [NetTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752250.aspx) basic example from msdn. See if this can help you.

**EDIT:**

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297756/wcf-service-library-with-nettcpbinding) is a related SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see  section in your config file, can u please 
please add this

```
<netTcpBinding>

 <binding name="WindowsSecured">
 <security mode="none"/> 
 </binding> 

</netTcpBinding>
```