# WCF TCP Binding

Tags: wcf-binding

how to implement the TCP binding in WCF ???

If I select TCP as binding then it ask for Address for the endpoint...and default given is net.tcp://

What should be the endpoint and base address here ? how can I specify that ???

Please give me step by step info as I am new to WCF Binding world...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question, I believe it contains both an answer to your question and pointers to more references.

[WCF Service netTCPbinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356739/wcf-service-nettcpbinding)