# wcf service in IIS with a TCP binding

Tags: wcf

where can I found more details about configuring IIS to support a TCP Binding?

Comment: http://www.letmegooglethatforyou.com/?q=wcf+tcp+binding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438338/wcf-tcp-binding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356739/wcf-service-nettcpbinding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297756/wcf-service-library-with-nettcpbinding

Answer (score 1):

You can either look in Google, or here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx